# Linq returning copies of objects

Tags: c#, linq

```
var top100 = (from m in _messages
              where m.IsSent == false
              select m).Take(100);

foreach (var message in top100)
{
    message.IsSent = _sms.SendSMS(message.Source, message.Destination, message.TextMessage);
}

var count = _messages.Count(x => x.IsSent);
```

I cannot understand why the variable count is equal to 0. I would have thought that I was working with references to my message objects, but if count is 0, does that mean I'm working with copies? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be that SendSMS returns false?

Comment: I assume that the count of `top100` is not zero?

Comment: When stepping through my code, SendSMS does return true, and yes, top100 does have objects in it.

Comment: If you are inspecting `count` in the debugger, make sure you are doing so on a line below what you are showing here. If you break on the `var count = …` line it will not yet be set.

Comment: @Jay: Yep, I am already doing that.

Comment: Are messages and _messages pointing at the same list?

Comment: Is the type of message a `class` or `struct`?

Comment: Is some other code manipulating _messages in another thread? Is message.IsSent correctly set to true in the foreach loop?

Comment: Could you simplify your code so that you could post it here in full and we could reproduce the issue?

Comment: To determine the issue, we will need a **reproducible** code sample.

Comment: I investigated stepping through things very slowly, and noticed some strange results. count was quite often equal to the amount of times I saw true being returned, before I simply hit F5 to run through the rest of the collection. It turns out that SendSMS had a Random object being instantiated inside the SendSMS method. After moving this to the class level, results are as expected. I think Aaron Anodide gave the closest answer, so I'll award the answer to him. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried investigating your question and I didn't reproduce it so it makes me wonder if your IsSent is actually false and that's why you get your result.

```
void Main()
{
    var top100 = (from m in Messages where m.IsSent == false select m).Take(100);   
    foreach (var message in top100) { 
        message.IsSent = true; 
    }
    var count = Messages.Count(x => x.IsSent); 
    Console.WriteLine(count);
}
List<Message> Messages {
    get {
        if(_messagesList == null) {
            _messagesList = new List<Message>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                _messagesList.Add(new Message { IsSent = false });
        }
        return _messagesList;
    }
}
List<Message> _messagesList;
class Message {
    public bool IsSent { get; set; }
}
```

Output is `100`

Answer (score 1):

Just grab the count from `top100` after the sms processing.

`var count = top100.Count(m => m.IsSent);`

Let's pretend a count was returning with your current code.  It would return a count that wasn't correct for the *100* messages you had just attempted.  So say `_messages` had 101 messages in it.  100 of them had `IsSent` set to false, and one had `IsSent` set to true.  After setting `IsSent` to true on the 100 you get in your first line, `_messages.Count(x => x.IsSent)` would return 101.  Depending on what you are using `count` for, 101 might not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with Enumerable. Take does a yield result, so unless you add a `.ToList()` at the end, your `.Count()` call will essentially just re-apply the `from m in _messages
              where m.IsSent == false` Returning the next 100 unsent messages.

Add a `.ToList()` to your initial pull of 100 then the `.Count()` will evaluate against the initial 100 you processed.

Comment: The OP is counting against `_messages`, not `top100`, so this isn't the issue.